# How to update Android OS on a device through an App

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to update the Android OS through an App(Using Android API or any other API/) after checking if a newer Android version is available in the market/Playstore The Use Case required to be supported here is as follows:

1. The App starts and checks the version of the installed Android OS
2. It then finds the version of available Android OS in the
   Playstore/other repository for that device
3. Then it compares the two version and if the available version is
   newer, then it installs the new Android version on the device

How can it be implemented , especially the third point ? I do not want to root the device for that, so if there is any way to achieve this, please help ....